# How to do cumulative sum for calculated field in data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to calculate a cumulative rate of ROAS (Revenue / Cost) in data studio.
There is daily data of Revenue and Cost, and I can make a cumulative sum graph of Revenue and Cost like following,
but do not know how to make a cumulative graph of  sum(Revenue)/sum(Cost).

Could anyone help me out?

[image: cumulative sum graph of Revenue and Cost]

Comment: I created a calculated field like sum(revenue) / sum(cost), and chose running sum, but it gave me a very wired result.  Do anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I created a calculated field with `Revenue / Cost` (without explicit SUM) and choose `Sum` as aggregation and `Running sum` as Running calculation. The result seems to be correct:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Damião for the answer.  While this is not what is expected. For example, Mar 2's Running ROAS,  I am expecting 1.67 which is  (2+3)/(1+2), and Mar 3 is 1.75 which is (2+3+2) / (1+2+1) .  I just want to calculate the monthly to day ROAS.  I know it is tricky to do this in data studio..